# Subdomain filter - Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, wordpress

Error: Only variables should be passed by reference in * on line 6

Line 6:

```
$subdomain = array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
```

can i just ignore this warning? It bothers me to leave it behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because array_shift expects a pointer to an array explode is giving an array, but because your not saving it to a variable your not actually passing a pointer to it you passing the whole array.

```php
$array = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$subdomain = array_shift($array);
```

A bit more of an explanation.

`explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` Creates an array,
`$array =`  means set $array to be a pointer/refference to that array

`array_shift` take a pointer/reference to an array it will not accept a array directly, this used to be denoted by `array_shift(&$array)`;

but the reason for this is because array_shift alters the original array so if you don't have access to the original array saved it's going to do work that you then can't access so it's pointless load